# Problem with concurrent execution of static and non-static synchronized methods?

Tags: java

In the following example

1. What will happen if different threads try to access the static and
   non-static synchronized methods concurrently, and in turn try to
   change the static data using the two methods?
2. Is there  any problems using do-while loop of the run() method to
   create a new object of the class BadDesign for every non-static
   synchronized method call?
3. Is this Java code properly synchronized or not?

Here is the sample code illustrating my questions:

BadDesign.java

```
public final class BadDesign{

    private static int sensitiveData;

    public synchronized static void changeDataViaStaticMethod(int a){
        //... updating the sensitiveData
        sensitiveData = a;
    }


    public synchronized void changeDataViaNonStaticMethod(int b){
        //... updating the sensitiveData
        sensitiveData = b;
    }


    public static void showSensitiveDataStatic(){
        System.out.println("Static: " + Thread.currentThread().getName()+ " - " + sensitiveData);
    }


    public void showSensitiveData(){
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - " + sensitiveData);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){

        new Thread(new TestThread11()).start();
        new Thread(new TestThread11()).start();
    }
}
```

And TestThread11.java

```
class TestThread11 implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
        int i = 0;

        do{
            BadDesign.changeDataViaStaticMethod(5);
            BadDesign.showSensitiveDataStatic();

            //... new object for every iteration

            //... so synchronization of non-static method

            //... doesn't really do anything significant here

            BadDesign bd = new BadDesign();
            bd.changeDataViaNonStaticMethod(10);
            bd.showSensitiveData();

        }while (i++ < 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm tired editing a post this very early in the morning. I will allow other keen editors to come up and take the fort. ;-)

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman - you guys don't sleep :P. Consider it edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The static and non-static data accessed by multiple threads are handled by different level of locks. The threads which access the non-static methods share object level lock(which is per object) where as to access static methods you need class level lock(which is 1 per Class)
2. There is no problem with the do-while loop, as

   ```
      BadDesign.changeDataViaStaticMethod(5); //needs BadDesign Class lock.     
      BadDesign.showSensitiveDataStatic();  //does not need any lock
   ```

and

```
       bd.changeDataViaNonStaticMethod(10); // needs lock for bd object.
       bd.showSensitiveData();              //does not need any lock
```

I hope that answers your questions.

Comment: ahh..ok. The code which you write in showSensitiveData() is never thread-safe. That means multiple threads can access this method at the same time, as its not synchronized. so if you write something like , incrementing some global value and expect it to show proper value in each thread, that might nob the case.

Answer (score 6):

The non-static version will allow two different threads to come in via different objects, acquire different locks and still access the same shared data. Fundamentally, that's not thread-safe, and basically makes the locks useless. You want any piece of shared data to be covered by *one* lock.

You can still use non-static methods if you really want to (e.g. if the result should be determined partly by instance data as well) but you should access the shared data via a shared lock, e.g.

```
private static final Object staticLock = new Object();

...

synchronized (staticLock)
{
    // Read or write static data
}
```

Comment: @chinchu: What do you mean? I've shown you has to use a synchronized statement. Do you mean using synchronized *methods*? If so, I would personally avoid those to start with - avoid exposing your lock unless you really have to.

Comment: @chichu: Right - a synchronized method is basically equivalent to having `synchronized(this)` or `synchronized(TheDeclaringClass.class)` statement in. Not a good idea, as then anyone else locking on the same monitor can cause a deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is coursework of some kind. It seems the point of this particular problem is to highlight two fundamental basics in Java

1. Any object can serve as a monitor in Java
2. How `synchronized` implicitly uses the current object instance as lock

Point 1 is a lot about understanding what a monitor is. I invite you to study the relevant section of the Java language specification, [Threads and Locks](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.1). A monitor is something that a thread can **lock** and **unlock**. When one threads locks it, any other thread attempting to lock that specific monitor will wait (block) until the first thread unlocks it.

Point 2 is about a compiler feature in Java. When you specify something as `synchronized` without explicitly indicating which monitor to use, Java will use the instance of the object being called. If, however, the method is static, it will use the instance of the objects **class** (`java.lang.Class`) as monitor. What does this mean in reality? Since there is only one unique, global, instance of each class object in a classloader context, a static method will only have one monitor. In contrast, an instance method will use the instance of the object being called as monitor so each object will have it's own monitor. **Static** methods are synchrionized globally, **instance** method are synchronized for each specific instance of the class.